# Flutter won't build iOS release - DONE

Tags: ios, firebase, gradle, flutter

The thing is that I try to build a iOS release for a flutter app but it crashes I search for results about the errors but found nothing hope someone could help.

NOTE : The app launch and works perfectly on both IOS and Android but doesn't build on any of them. here is my post about the Android problem :
Android post

You can find below the result of my "flutter doctor -v" and "flutter build ios -v".

**flutter doctor -v :**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A602, locale en-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.5 at /Users/axel/flutter
    • Framework revision 1aedbb1835 (4 days ago), 2019-10-17 08:37:27 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/axel/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.1, Build version 11A1027
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.39.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.5.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 10
      (API 29) (emulator)
    • iPhone 11 Pro             • DB06E423-957F-41AA-99D0-05735D90C30B • ios         •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-1 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

**flutter build ios -v :**

```
[ +118 ms] "flutter ios" took 19,172ms.
Encountered error while building for device.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      BuildIOSCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:94:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:490:18)
#3      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#9      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#10     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:552:7)
#11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#13     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#14     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#17     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
#18     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the problem, First i wasn't working with the stable flutter version i was with 1.10.x and going back to flutter 1.9.x-prefix.x made it run back again but the build din't work anymore, the thing that was making the build crash was that with the latest xCode version and since i was working with firebase cloud messaging i need to add back the mobile provision back in xCode part of my flutter app. – Axel Frau just now   Edit   Delete
 i followed this tutorial : [Firebase Cloud messaging](https://medium.com/flutterpub/enabling-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-with-flutter-39b08f2ed723) to do this as on the project i'm working on somebody else did it before me.